# ASP.NET: Get node selected on an ASP.NET TreeView by Client Side JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, treeview

I need to know the selected node's depth from a ASP.NET Treeview on client side.

Is there anyway to know this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I like doing it this way and if time permits I'll try and find another method;

```
        var id = TreeView2_Data.selectedNodeID.value;  //Get the Selectednode id of tv with asp.net id of TreeView2
    if (id.length > 0) {
        var selectedNode = document.getElementById(id);  //Get the Selectnode object  -> selectedNode.innerText will give you the text of the node
        if ((typeof (selectedNode) != "undefined") && (selectedNode != null)) {
            //Determine the depth of the select node
            var nodeDepth = selectedNode.host.split('\\\\').length  // the separator is the default single \. Tv adds the extra on and of course we have to add 2 for the string literals.
            //node depth wil always be one more than the real node depth, so root is one.
            if (nodeDepth >= 4) {   
                //Do stuff or return value
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps. Post back if you find an alternative.